# What are the advantages of tracking-mode SSL vs. COOKIE?

Tags: session, tomcat, jsf-2, session-cookies

I am creating a JSF application deployed in Tomcat/EE (with CLIENTCERTs). By default, the `jsessionid` (generated with a [SecureRandom](https://lkubaski.wordpress.com/2013/02/16/how-tomcat-and-jetty-generate-the-sessionid/), so it looks safe) was set in the URL, which I disabled for [security reasons](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A2-Broken_Authentication_and_Session_Management) by changing the [SessionTrackingMode](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/SessionTrackingMode.html).

Now I am trying to find the security advantages/disadvantages of using:

`<tracking-mode>SSL</tracking-mode>` vs. `<tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>`

(considering security almost always has an impact on performance and other variables). Probably one of the problems is that I do not know what SSL tracking-mode exactly does. [This API documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/SessionTrackingMode.html) is not very clear.

When should I use one or the other?

*PS: I know this is not specific of Tomcat or JSF but I need to give context to the question*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would recommend the use of cookie-based session-tracking over SSL session-tracking for a few reasons:

1. Using SSL session-tracking may prevent explicit (user-initiated) logouts
2. Using SSL session-tracking may prevent sessions from being terminated due to inactivity-timeouts
3. Using SSL session-tracking may cause unexpected logouts (due to TLS renegotiation, which changes the TLS session-id)
4. Using SSL session-tracking will make it harder to debug, troubleshoot, and generally manipulate your own application if necessary (telling a client to clear their cookies is easier and less arcane than asking them to expire their TLS session-ids)

FWIW, IBM WebSphere [has dropped support for SSL-based session-tracking](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rprs_sesd.html) as of version 7.0 (circa 2008).

I don't see any advantage to using SSL-based session-tracking.

Comment: This was useful as a general rule. However, I would like to check if this really applies to my case... I am using client certs, so [1] there is no explicit "logout", only when the user closes the browser. [2] There is no real time-out, since as long as the browser is open, the session is active. [3] A forced logout would only asked the user to choose again a certificate (a bit annoying but not disastrous) [4] This actually applies. So as far as I understand, only point 4 will justify cookies over SSL. Is there any other reason? PS. I tried to find WebSphere reasons unsuccessfully

Comment: I can't really think of any other reasons. My experience is that SSL-based session-tracking is rarely used in the wild, so you may get a lot of shrugs when asking questions, as you did here with me. The use of client-cert for authentication is definitely important information which I apparently ignored at first, but (HTTP) sessions are distinct from an authenticated user, so they will have timeouts, etc. That may be confusing for the user (or application) if they don't have to login again, but their (HTTP) session has timed-out and there are things unexpectedly missing in the session.

Comment: You may get better feedback by asking on the Tomcat users' mailing list, since there is a higher concentration of users and admins there who might have an opinion about client-cert-based authentication and the implications of that authentication strategy on session-tracking strategy.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. I will wait for a couple of weeks to see if somebody else has an answer and otherwise I will mark this as the solution

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add some details to @Christopher Schultz's answer.

- If your application is **not using client certificates**, then it might be more convenient to use **cookies**. The reason is potential invalidation of sessions as Christopher pointed out. I have not tested this, though, it is just a theoretical impression.
- If client certificates are used, I have verified that tracking sessions via SSL connections is **completely valid**. I have been doing this for a while and I have not found any problem, nor unexpected error/logout, nor tedious process for users to have to login again. In my opinion, in some situations SSL might even be a cleaner way to keep
  sessions. Note that developers might have to keep some security
  considerations when using cookies (e.g. [HttpOnly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly), [cookie secure
  flag](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag#Testing_for_the_Secure_Flag)...). I am not saying this is a reason to choose SSL
  tracking, since developers might have to keep some security
  considerations with SSL tracked sessions too, I am just saying I am
  not currently aware of them, while I am aware of the cookie ones.
- If you opt for SSL tracking and you are using **JSF** (Java EE) and e.g. `@ViewScoped`s, then you will have problems when using the insecure HTTP, because JSF will not be able to track the session if no TLS/SSL is in place. So if you need JSF with scopes that need tracking the session, and need HTTP access to your application, then you should go for COOKIE tracking. On the other hand, if you always use HTTPS, or have no need to e.g. `@ViewScoped`, then SSL tracking is totally fine.

Comment: Hah! Non-secure HTTP... so quaint. :) Good point about TLS certificates not working over non-secure HTTP. Sounds dumb, but if your session-tracking mechanism requires TLS and yet you allow insecure (let's say pre-authenticated) access which uses sessions, you may be in trouble.